# struggling to set period of time on red for 4 sec and to display led countdown

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

im currently struggling for my microcontroller project in 8086. Supposedly, i need to set the period on red for 4 seconds. I already tried a lot of ways to figure this out but it always turns the other way. Also, i need to make the led display running and counting the the period of the red light duration which is 4 seconds. here the code:

```
 ; controlling external device with 8086 microprocessor.
; realistic test for c:\emu8086\devices\Traffic_Lights.exe

#start=Traffic_Lights.exe#

name "traffic" 


mov ax, all_red
out 4, ax


mov si, offset situation


next:
mov ax, [si]
out 4, ax   



; wait 5 seconds (5 million microseconds)
mov     cx, 4Ch    ;    004C4B40h = 5,000,000
mov     dx, 4B40h
mov     ah, 86h
int     15h   


add si, 2 ; next situation
cmp si, sit_end
jb  next
mov si, offset situation
jmp next    

            

;                        FEDC_BA98_7654_3210
situation        dw      0000_0011_0000_1100b
s1               dw      0000_0110_1001_1010b
s2               dw      0000_1000_0110_0001b
s3               dw      0000_1000_0110_0001b
s4               dw      0000_0100_1101_0011b
sit_end = $


all_red          equ     0000_0010_0100_1001b
```

to see the countdown in led display

Comment: It's unclear what you need and how your system is set up. It seems like the initial `all_red` is immediately overwritten. If you need 4 seconds why do you wait for 5? Also if you need to count down you presumably want to just wait 1 second then update the display.